# How to Create a tree from unsorted doubly Link List

Tags: java, data-structures

I am struggling to create a Tree for a unsorted LinkList where each Node contain three instance variable

1. id
2. data
3. parentid

and LinkList is of datatype node no specific type of tree is needed just basic tree with child and parent relation

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), [idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Divyang Mistry by parentid, do you mean the id of the previous node, because right now it's just a linked list, so can I consider parentid to be pointer to next node ?

Comment: I am not able to visualize how to make a complete tree. I really dont know where to start from. What ever I have done is iterate through the list through recursion and find the root and stored it in a variable

Comment: @zenwraight I will send you the structure of the iteration how the data is comming in the LinkList

Comment: @DivyangMistry if you can paste an example of how the linked list looks and what output do you need, how the tree will look, then i can help you out very easily

Comment: @zenwraight below is the ouput of the list

Comment: Pojo{id=4, parent_id=2, name=C}
Pojo{id=5, parent_id=2, name=D}
Pojo{id=7, parent_id=3, name=E}
Pojo{id=6, parent_id=3, name=F}
Pojo{id=8, parent_id=6, name=FB}
Pojo{id=1, parent_id=0, name=root}
Pojo{id=2, parent_id=1, name=A}
Pojo{id=3, parent_id=1, name=B}

Comment: Ok this is the list you have and you need to make a tree out of this right, so basically it should just be a tree (in other terms a graph) . Am I right ?

Comment: And the output will be like this:

Comment: Pojo{id=1, parent_id=0, name=root}
 --> Pojo{id=2, parent_id=1, name=A}
 ----> Pojo{id=4, parent_id=2, name=C}
 ----> Pojo{id=5, parent_id=2, name=D}
 --> Pojo{id=3, parent_id=1, name=B}
 ----> Pojo{id=7, parent_id=3, name=E}
 ----> Pojo{id=6, parent_id=3, name=F}

Comment: @zenwraight Yes But it must represent parent and child relation

Comment: Got it and you are comfortable with java I see, let me post an answer for this in like 20 mins, this is pretty straight forward method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start looking at this problem by taking an example.

Below is the list data provided to us

```
Pojo{id=4, parent_id=2, name=C} 
Pojo{id=5, parent_id=2, name=D} 
Pojo{id=7, parent_id=3, name=E} 
Pojo{id=6, parent_id=3, name=F} 
Pojo{id=8, parent_id=6, name=FB} 
Pojo{id=1, parent_id=0, name=root} 
Pojo{id=2, parent_id=1, name=A} 
Pojo{id=3, parent_id=1, name=B}
```

Let's Assume we have been provided with the size of the list i.e `7` in the above case.

Now Based on what information Author has provided in the comments, I am assuming that this is a list of Pojo objects i.e `List<Pojo> pojoObjects;`

Now we will be storing our tree (graph) in a data structure like this -
`ArrayList<ArrayList<Pojo>> finalTree = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Pojo>>(7);`

Now we can just iterate over our list - `pojoObjects` and we can then check what is the parent id and add this particular Pojo object to that list element.

Something like this:-

```
for(Object pojo: pojoObjects) {
    int parentId = pojo.parent_id;
    ArrayList<Pojo> atThisIndex = finalTree[parentId];
    atThisIndex.add(pojo);
    finalTree[parentId] = atThisIndex;
}
```

Now after this loop our output will look something like this:-

```
0 -> Pojo{id=1, parent_id=0, name=root}
1 -> Pojo{id=2, parent_id=1, name=A} , Pojo{id=3, parent_id=1, name=B}
2 -> Pojo{id=4, parent_id=2, name=c} , Pojo{id=5, parent_id=2, name=D}
3 -> Pojo{id=7, parent_id=3, name=E} , Pojo{id=6, parent_id=3, name=F}
4 -> {}
5 -> {}
6 -> {}
7 -> {}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @DivyangMistry have a look and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes this will be the output and it's tree only, like when you are at element 1, you can then traverse to 2 and then to either 4 or 5.... based on the next id present in the Pojo object

Comment: @DivyangMistry if this answers helps in anyway you should mark it as Answer so that community knows that it's done

Comment: its perfect thank you only one issue how will I iterate the list to get all the childs for parent id 2 can you help me out with that

Comment: If you want children for parent id 2, then finalTree[2] will return u ArrayList<Pojo> and it's size will be 2 because of node is 4 and 5

Comment: I hope you know how to make use of ArrayList othewrwise it's gonna be difficult for you

Comment: I know how to use it but there is one thing that I need to understand in this strucure what if the senario is there where the child is which I have got has more child in it suppose node 4 has 2 more child and 5 has one more in that scenario is this structure work

Comment: Yes this structure will work because each index of finalTree is an ArrayList<Pojo> which is dynamic in size, so not a problem at all

Comment: And one more thing if I put id =  1 I will get all the child and grand child from this strucure

Comment: When you access the index 1, you will get all the children of 1 as ArrayList<Pojo> now after that u will have to iterate over this List to get grandchildren of 1, it's like traversal, I hope you are getting my point

Comment: Ok I got it Thank you for you help

Comment: U welcome :) if you have any algo or ds related questions in future you can tag me in the comments of that question which u post

Comment: Ok I will tag you